# What do we call functions that return axioms / axiom schemata?

Tags: logic, terminology

Consider the function $\mathrm{Assoc}$ defined by:

$$\mathrm{Assoc}(X,*) = (\forall x,y,z \in X)((x*y)*z=x*(y*z))$$

This is a function that accepts symbols $X$ and $*$ and returns the axiom (a syntactical entity, not a truthvalue) that $*$ is associative on $X$.

Is there a traditional name for such functions?

Comment: Such is usually introduced as a *shorthand* or as an *extension of the language*.

Answer (score 1):

The following are terms that are used to describe functions like these (with formulae as outcomes):

- Shorthand;
- Extension of the language;
- (Definitional) Abbreviation,

where the latter two are typically used when the arguments are variables, e.g. $\text{comm}(x,y)$ for $xy = yx$).

I don't think there is specific terminology for such functions returning "axioms" (and of course, *every* formula can potentially be an axiom of some structure, albeit some formulae are more common than others :)).

Answer (score 0):

Axiom scheme is similar concept but I have never seen it introduced as a function.